# Set of points - exclude a point

Tags: calculus

I want to make a set of the points given out by x and y axis where `1 <= x <= 3` and `1 <= y <= 2`. The point `(1, 1)` is excluded though. I could write:

`S = {(x, y) : x ε {1, 2, 3}, y ε {1, 2}}` but in this way, the point `(1, 1)` is included. How can I implement this to my set?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=(\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2\})\setminus\{(1,1)\}$$